# CKEditor forceAsPasteAsPlainText not working when set in replace()

Tags: ckeditor

I have an instance of CKEditor 3.6.3 set up like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("notice_text", {
                                    toolbar : "Mini", 
                                    enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, 
                                    fillEmptyBlocks : false,
                                    forcePasteAsPlainText : true,
                                    skin : "office2003", 
                                    width : 375,
                                    height : 100
                                    });
```

For this textarea:

```
<textarea id="notice-text" name="notice_text" rows="5"></textarea>
```

`Mini` is a toolbar defined in the config.js.

All the settings in replace work fine except `forcePasteAsPlainText`.

However, when I set `forcePasteAsPlainText` in the config.js it works. Like so in the config.js:

```
 config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

Setting it in the config.js applies it to all CKEditors on the site and I wanted it to apply to this one `textarea`.

I took a look at the [CKEditor changelogs](http://ckeditor.com/whatsnew) and didn't see anything that would address this with an update.

I thought you could set it in the `replace` function. Is that not possible or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried updating to latest CKEditor 3.6.x? I believe that I saw this issue fixed some time ago. And it WFM on trunk.

Comment: @Reinmar I saw that they addressed an issue with Firefox and `forcePasteAsPlainText` but updating may be my next step. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `removePlugins :  "pastefromword"`  to your config.

```
CKEDITOR.replace("notice_text", {
                                    toolbar : "Mini", 
                                    enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, 
                                    fillEmptyBlocks : false,
                                    forcePasteAsPlainText : true,
                                    skin : "office2003", 
                                    removePlugins :  "pastefromword" ,  
                                    width : 375,
                                    height : 100
                                    });
```

This force exists plugin `pastetext` in your config, and `pastefromword` not exists in. Run again ==> Its work!